# What happens if you leave your Clash of Clans game for a week?

Tags: clash-of-clans

What happens if you don't do something to your game for a week?

Are there any consequences?

Comment: does getting raided and having all your resources stolen count as a consequence?

Comment: I have noticed when I don't play for a few days I stop getting raided notifications

Answer (score 13):

There is no consequences for leaving your game for a week... The only thing that would happen is that your base would be raided (loss of resources), unless you have bought a shield.

All shield and trophy mechanics will still remain as if you were still playing; you gain shield for losing defenses, lose trophies (or earn if someone screws up their attack), etc.