# What would happen to my inactive Clash of Clans account?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Most of the villages we see during attack research seem to be active. Sometimes you find an opponent that has been inactive for a couple of days and bingo, his extractors are full. but I still consider this as an *active* player.

Let's assume I delete the app or I do not connect to the app for several months. What would happen then ? Would I still visible when opponents go for matchmaking ? Would I earn an infinite shield because of inactivity ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens if you leave your Clash of Clans game for a week?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/184174/what-happens-if-you-leave-your-clash-of-clans-game-for-a-week)

Comment: @aytimothy not really ; the point of my question is to know what happens after several months of inactivity, and not a couple of days

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I took a break **for about a year** and just reinstalled it for this question.  Below are screenshots of my base immediately after opening the app.

**All of my collectors were almost full, I was kicked out of my Clan, I am not placed in any league, and my land has a lot of trees/rubbish on it (usually I had it clean).**

Their EULA must have changed, as I had to accept this again:
[image]

Collectors almost full and rubbish everywhere: 
[image]

Top of defense log:
[image]

Bottom of defense log (30 days max I guess?), was still visible to attackers, **no infinite shield**.
[image]

Proof, nothing in my attack log:
[image]

I also had a lot of notes about the updates and changes they made to read through but my base was not deleted.

Comment: To add to this, from what I have been reading longer periods of inactivity seems to put you lower down onto the matchmaking list. So you will have a gradual decrease in raids the longer you are inactive.

Answer (score 6):

If you are inactive, or delete the app, it will be just like if you are away for a couple of days, except longer. Your collectors and mines will be full, and you will have been raided. A Lot.